# Can I change the current launch configuration in VS Code with a command

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation, vscode-debugger

[image]

We are calling the command `workbench.action.debug.start` remotely for automation purposes, but are stuck with the manually configured current launch configuration as shown in the screenshot.

Is anybody aware of a way to change it, programmatically, using the name value of another launch configuration in launch.json.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of two possible options (although neither may work for you...).

You can make a keybinding like this:

```json
 {
    "key": "alt+j",                      // whatever you want
    "command": "debug.startFromConfig",
    "args": {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "workspace launch.json Launch Chrome against localhost",
        
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "file": "${workspaceRoot}/test.html"
        
        // "preLaunchTask": "echo Builtin Variables"  // can't get it to find a pre-launch task
    }
  }
```

`debug.startFromConfig` is a built-in command, so should work remotely.  The problem I have had with that keybinding in the past is that all possible launch configuration arguments were not supported.  The ones I showed work for me, but `preLaunchTask` didn't seem to work.  But try your launch configuration arguments and see if they work.

Secondly, I wrote an extension [Launch Configs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config) that does support all the arguments but might not work in your remote environment.  You would make a setting like:

```json
  "launches": {
    "test-debug": "Launch File (Test Bed)",
    "Start2Debuggers": "Start 2 node debuggers (Test Bed)",
    "Start2DebuggersArray": [
      "First Debugger (Test Bed)",
      "Second Debugger (Test Bed)"
    ],
    "LaunchChrome": "workspace launch.json Launch Chrome against localhost (Test Bed)",
    "LaunchFirstDebugger": "First Debugger (Test Bed)"
  },
```

where the key (like `LaunchChrome`) is a name you make up and will use in a keybinding.  The value for that key is the `name` of some launch configuration.  You should get intellisense completions for available launch configurations.  The keybinding would then be

```json
{
  "key": "alt+j",            // whatever you want here
  "command": "launches.LaunchChrome",
  // "when": ""
}
```

and that will launch the matching `LaunchChrome` argument from the setting.

Comment: Thx for your answer. In your first option example, where is the name of the specific configuration, so I can give it a go?

Comment: @noontz It is in your `launch.json` file, typically under `.vscode`.  Although they can go elsewhere too.  Each launch configuration should have a `name` argument.

Comment: Thx, and yes, I am aware of that. Sorry for not being concise in my comment. I am referring to the first code sample in your answer. Where in this code sample, do you specifiy the name of the specific launch configuration in launch.json to initiate?

Comment: @noontz If you are referring to the `debug.startFromConfig` version there is a `name` argument there.  If you are referring to the `launches` example, the values of the key: value pairs, like `"test-debug": "Launch File (Test Bed)",` - that second part `Launch File (Test Bed)` is the name.  You should get intellisense suggestions for the names.  The `(Test Bed)` is just a workspace name reference automatically added by the extension to aid in disambiguating launch names which may be the same in different multi-root workspaces.

Comment: Couldn't make  debug.startFromConfig  work with the compound I was using, but your extension works like a charm with Elio Struyf's Remote Control.  Thx again!